# click Notification just work once

Tags: android, push-notification

i'm using a custom notification receiver and show them in the notification bar. for testing, i send 2 notifications to my phone.
i close the app, click on the first notification, the app open!
i close the app, click on the second notification, nothing happens!

```
 private void generateNotification(Context context, String title, JSONObject json, String text) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, home.class);

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationManager mNotifM = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(text)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text))
                        .setTicker(text)
                        .setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 500);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        mNotifM.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have different request code for different notifications. have a look at below code

```
Random random = new Random();
int NOTIFICATION_ID = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, NOTIFICATION_ID,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: Not working for now

Answer (score 1):

Use different request codes for each pending intent or do not use FLAG_ONE_SHOT flag

```
static count = 0;
...

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, count++, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```